# How to show that the graph $y^2=\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}x}$ does not consist of circles?

Tags: circles

The question in the textbook gives the graph of $y^2=\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}x}$ which looks like this. [image]

It then asks to prove that although the graph looks like it is made from circles, it is not. I'm not sure how to prove this exactly. I tried to show this by finding the derivative which is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\pi\cos{(\pi/2)x}}{4y}$. Then I thought since the numerator isn't a linear function it wouldn't be a circle but I'm not sure if that conclusion makes any sense. Could someone clarify how could I disprove that the graph is made of circles?

Comment: your work is correct

Comment: $y^2=\sin\dfrac{\pi}{2}x$. Consider closed part of graph for $x\in[0;2]$. Minimum $x$ is 0 maximum $x$ is 2. Minimum $y$ is -1, maximum $y$ is 1. If it was circle then its center must be $(1;0)$ and radius must be $1$, then its equation must be $y^2+(x-1)^2=1\Rightarrow y^2=2x-x^2$.

Comment: Other way to prove is to consider 4 points of closed part of graph, which form no inscribed quadrilateral. For example: $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,0)$, $(1/2,1/2^{1/4})$.

Comment: Probably the simplest way is just to notice that if it was a circle then the coordinates would have to satisfy the equation of a circle. For example, for $0 \leq x \leq 2,$ we need every point $(x, y)$ on the curve to satisfy some equation like $(x-1)^2+y^2=1.$ But we have an expression for $y^2$ as a function of $\sin$, so this implies that $\sin$ is a polynomial, which is obviously false because $\sin$ has infinitely many roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more geometric approach. The pieces are identical since $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$ is periodic so it's sufficient to show any one of them is not a circle. Consider $x\in[0,2]$ and suppose to the contrary that the graph were a circle with center $O$. Points $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(2,0)$ are on the graph so $O$ must lie on the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$, which is the line $x=1$. Similarly, $C=(1,1)$ and $D=(1,-1)$ are on the graph so O must be on the line $y=0$, the perpendicular bisector of segment $CD$. Thus, the lines $x=1$ and $y=0$ intersect at $O$, i.e. $O=(1,0)$, and the radius is equal to $OA=1$. Point $E=\left(\frac 13,\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)$ is on the graph as well. From the distance formula, we have
$$OE=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac 13\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 }=\sqrt{\frac{17}{18}}\ne 1,$$
which is a contradiction.